# Any way to get a clean Reputation on XBL?

Tags: xbox-360

I've been on Xbox Live for a couple of years. I mainly play fighting games online. I'm competent but not really amazing at the ones I play. I don't use the microphone, and I only send insulting messages to people who send them to me first. But I looked at my reputation the other day and discovered to my surprise that I am marked for avoidance by ***78%*** of the people I've played with. Apparently I'm a bad sportsman (not even sure what this means in the context of fighting games), I'm disruptive (???), and quit early (maybe my internet connection has been worse than it seems to me?).

I don't really feel like I've been judged fairly and, whether you believe me or not, I want to know if there's anything I can do to undo my rep and get a clean slate.

Comment: Do you mean anyway besides buying a new account?

Comment: Xbox is not going to ban you or anything. Unless its a serious event. Reputation its a nice way of saying "I just don't want to play a match against this person again." But if you are getting reported then Xbox may look at your profile.

Comment: 78% only means 78% of the people who left reviews marked you as Avoid, NOT 78% of all people who you played with online. My guess would be 11 out of 14 people left an avoid review, while 3 left a positive review. I generally find that people tend to only leave negative reviews when they get beat, etc.. The review system only really affects who you might play with or not play with in Xbox Live matches, but it doesn't even assure that. Check the Player Review video on this page to learn a bit about it http://www.xbox.com/en-US/Community/xbox101/Play-on-Xbox-LIVE.

Comment: tl;dr Don't worry about it, it doesn't matter really.

Comment: If it's only 78% of people who have reviewed me, then it's terribly worded, cause right now it says 22% of players either didn't have anything to say or wanted to play with me again, which implies it's factoring in everybody I've played. I'm sure the only reason I'm getting marked down is cause I'm beating these guys. It just seems frustrating.

Comment: The reputation system is completely ambiguous.  I SINCERELY doubt that 85% of people I've played have submitted negative reviews of me, while only 15% of players have *done nothing* or submitted positive reviews.  Either way, I have a friend who was forced to change his Gamertag after beating some people at Halo 3; they immediately flagged his gamertag as offensive.  It was 'Aim Here77'

Comment: @DoozerBlake You ought to post that as an answer.

Answer (score 11):

You could always try to balance your reputation by playing games with a cooperative focus, or team-based shooters such as Team Fortress 2 and Left 4 Dead. You receive a lot of friend invites in games like these which you can turn into positive reviews fairly easily. Otherwise, if you continue to play fighting games, you can try to offer helpful advice to players you beat or congratulations to players who beat you.

For completeness, the Xbox 360 player review system works like this: You can either prefer a player or choose a reason that a player is to be avoided. Those reasons fall into three categories: Communication, Game Behavior, and Player Skill. Bad reviews for Player skill do not affect your reputation (although being reported for being `too good' is hardly a bad thing) so we will ignore them. Of the others you will want to avoid Trash Talking, Unpleasant Language, and having a Disruptive Voice. You said that you didn't use a microphone, so most of these do not apply to you, but mic users should turn off their microphone when not in use and make sure it is functioning properly as to not create static and you will want to edit any comments you feel the need to make after a match.

Your negative game behavior can also be marked as Overly Aggressive, Unsporting Conduct or Quit Early. Play until the end, don't cheat, and show the other players that its all in the name of fun every once in a while to avoid tags like these.

Answer (score 0):

I'm 80 percent avoided, been that for 5 years. Don't worry about it. That avoided figure normally means that you have owned people or you was too good for them to beat you. Everyone likes to win no one likes to lose, if they avoid you it normally means there is a less chance of being matched up against you, but even that doesn't happen.

I was playing Grifball and a guy just betrayed his entire team for 5 rounds. I avoided him, then 5 games later I was matched up with him again so really the rep system doesn't mean anything. My advice is try to play as normally as you can, beat everyone in your path, and also try to get your bad rep up to 95 percent. Now that would be something.

Comment: As someone who has played a lot of fighting games online, I more or less agree with this (aside from the last bit). I've gotten tons of "unsportsmanlike" or "overly aggressive" reviews just by simply playing the game as intended and winning, never disconnecting, never taunting, never sending messages, etc. A lot of people seem to seek "retribution" when you beat them, and misuse the reviews system as a way to do it.